# How to get the HTML output from a DataGrid?

Tags: .net, html, datagrid, webforms, render

I was wondering if there was a way to some how get the HTML output of a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx).  I want the *raw* HTML after the data has been bound to the grid.  Is there some sort of overload for the render method I can use to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(outputBuffer)))
{
    yourDataGrid.RenderControl(writer);
}
outputBuffer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you did override the Render method and call the base Render method, the HTML would be in the stream.

Perhaps the [Control Adapter](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/21/asp-net-2-0-control-adapter-architecture.aspx) architecture may help whatever you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach in your class (derived from DataGrid):

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    base.Render(hw);

    string html = ProcessHtml(sw.ToString());

    writer.Writer(html);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
     /// use HtmlTextWriter to customize your output
}
```

Comment: How would I use that to get the RAW html after the data has been binded to the grid?

Comment: Ok, create a writer object and pass it to this function:
RenderContents(writer);  then the contents of the writer has the output you want.